# How to add Custom speech Recognition screen

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I don't want a blank screen to open when speech recognition intent is called as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
```

Either I would like to give my custom screen layout or I would like to make it transparent. Is there any possibility for this design in the current gdk?

Edit:

Try the new "Clay Shooter" game on glass which uses this feature of voice recognition. I want a similar option where the voice recognition is open in the background service while the display screen is doing its work. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to recognize speech immediately after a Voice Command from the Glass Home screen? Or something different... like recognize speech in your Live Card or Immersion?

Comment: I am trying to recognize speech in my live card and that is when i have to open RecognizeIntent which shows black screen.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class instead. It allows you to show your own UI / no UI at all while listening for speech.